# Grouping similar answers

Tags: statistical-significance, inference

So I have a set of 50 questions that take three types of answers: x, y, z. I will give the questions to 10 individuals and ask for their independent replies. I want to pick those six individuals that correlate the most. How do I do that?

Comment: Is it one choice test? All 50 questions have the same weight?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. This is going to be a pilot test. I will pick those six individuals who correlate the most to ask them further sets of questions.

Comment: I mean on each question individuals allowed to give one answer? Is all 50 questions are of the same importance for your correlation?

Comment: Ahh, right, I should have clarified that. Yes, only one answer per question. And yes, all questions are of the same importance. Thank you zlon!